# Oracle multi-row insert with returning into clause?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Oracle doesn't have easy support for multi-row inserts. However, I did find few workarounds ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9366325/145682), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602/145682)) to this. However, I didn't find an option where I can do multiple inserts and get the ID values back.

For e.g. here is a statement in postgresql:

```
insert into student (name, age) values ('monica', 23), ('saroop', 34) returning id
```

Assuming here the `student` table has some auto-generating `id` field, the above query will return as list of id values. (Two, in this case).

Does oracle pl/sql have something to this same effect?

Note: oracle pl/sql has something for single row inserts that return into a variable as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39798167/145682). However, this will fail for multi-row inserts.

Comment: Get the sequence ID's in the first step and then pass them with the data in the multi-row inserts using `identity` column  with `default` option

Answer (score 3):

This is a sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE student
  2  (
  3     id     NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  4     name   VARCHAR2 (20),
  5     age    NUMBER
  6  );

Table created.
```

If you try to use the `RETURNING` clause with a multi-row `insert`, it won't work (that's just how it is in Oracle; it *would* work with `update` or `delete`, though):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_ids  SYS.odcinumberlist;
  3  BEGIN
  4     INSERT INTO student (name, age)
  5        SELECT 'monica', 23 FROM DUAL
  6        UNION ALL
  7        SELECT 'saroop', 34 FROM DUAL
  8       RETURNING id
  9            BULK COLLECT INTO l_ids;
 10  END;
 11  /
     RETURNING id
               *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-06550: line 8, column 16:
PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06550: line 4, column 4:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored


SQL>
```

---

There's a workaround: first "prepare" rows to be inserted, use `forall` to insert them into the target table (now you can use `returning`), do whatever you want to do with returned values.

Types first:

```
SQL> CREATE TYPE r_stu AS OBJECT (name VARCHAR2 (20), age NUMBER);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TYPE t_stu AS TABLE OF r_stu;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

Procedure (read comments within the code):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_ids  SYS.odcinumberlist;
  3     l_tab  t_stu;
  4  BEGIN
  5     -- prepare rows to be inserted into the target STUDENT table
  6     WITH
  7        temp (name, age)
  8        AS
  9           (SELECT 'monica', 23 FROM DUAL
 10            UNION ALL
 11            SELECT 'saroop', 34 FROM DUAL)
 12     SELECT r_stu (name, age)
 13       BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab
 14       FROM temp;
 15
 16     -- L_TAB now contains all rows we need; insert them and use the RETURNING clause
 17     FORALL i IN l_tab.FIRST .. l_tab.LAST
 18        INSERT INTO student (name, age)
 19             VALUES (l_tab (i).name, l_tab (i).age)
 20          RETURNING id
 21               BULK COLLECT INTO l_ids;
 22
 23     -- these values have been inserted into the ID column
 24     FOR i IN l_ids.FIRST .. l_ids.LAST
 25     LOOP
 26        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Inserted ID value: ' || l_ids (i));
 27     END LOOP;
 28  END;
 29  /
Inserted ID value: 1
Inserted ID value: 2

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Table contents:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM student;

        ID NAME                        AGE
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 monica                       23
         2 saroop                       34

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT, regarding your worries about uniqueness being violated]**

You said:

> If one record had a column with unique value constraint violated, then the whole insert fails. With this above code, I think this is not the case

You're wrong. Here's a demo.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE student
  2  (
  3     id     NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  4     name   VARCHAR2 (20) CONSTRAINT uk_stu_name UNIQUE,
  5     age    NUMBER
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TYPE r_stu AS OBJECT (name VARCHAR2 (20), age NUMBER);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE TYPE t_stu AS TABLE OF r_stu;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Procedure; `monica` violates uniqueness

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_ids  SYS.odcinumberlist;
  3     l_tab  t_stu;
  4  BEGIN
  5     -- prepare rows to be inserted into the target STUDENT table
  6     WITH
  7        temp (name, age)
  8        AS
  9           (SELECT 'monica', 23 FROM DUAL
 10            UNION ALL
 11            SELECT 'saroop', 34 FROM DUAL
 12            UNION ALL
 13            SELECT 'monica', 44 FROM DUAL)  --> monica is duplicated, and will violate unique key
 14     SELECT r_stu (name, age)
 15       BULK COLLECT INTO l_tab
 16       FROM temp;
 17
 18     -- L_TAB now contains all rows we need; insert them and use the RETURNING clause
 19     FORALL i IN l_tab.FIRST .. l_tab.LAST
 20        INSERT INTO student (name, age)
 21             VALUES (l_tab (i).name, l_tab (i).age)
 22          RETURNING id
 23               BULK COLLECT INTO l_ids;
 24
 25     -- these values have been inserted into the ID column
 26     FOR i IN l_ids.FIRST .. l_ids.LAST
 27     LOOP
 28        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Inserted ID value: ' || l_ids (i));
 29     END LOOP;
 30  END;
 31  /
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.UK_STU_NAME) violated
ORA-06512: at line 19
```

Exception has been raised; you though that rows that didn't violate uniqueness will be inserted. Let's see:

```
SQL> select * from student;

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Happy?

Comment: Well, it is a solution. Thanks for this info. But the creation of types, etc is what makes me little non-confident to adopt it. I am using node-oracledb to connect to the db server and I was hoping for a simpler way. The tables in the application are managed at runtime. So in that sense it is impossible to keep track of what table is created and whether we require a bulk insert feature for it...

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps you should wait a little bit longer; there are really smart people here, someone might suggest a different - better - approach.

Comment: In postgresql the insert itself is atomic. If one record had a column with unique value constraint violated, then the whole insert fails. With this above code, I think this is not the case. We may need to wrap all of them in a transaction and commit if all data is inserted successfully (?)

Comment: I added another example which shows what happens if uniqueness is violated (basically, the same would happen for any other exception). Have a look, please.

Comment: Well, I tried this, and, got some error. I am running this via sql developer. Find the statements and error output here: https://gist.github.com/deostroll/7a6b324af0329373afbfa771ec6f3425#file-04-txt

Comment: Code you ran is different than the one I posted. Tool (SQL*Plus vs. SQL Developer) doesn't matter.

Answer (score -1):

Basically a variation of the @Littelfodds proposal, ommiting the PL/SQL stuff.

**TLDR** - use a *temporary table*, fill it first with your data enriched with the ID fetched from the sequence and publish the data in the *real table* in the second step.

*Table Setup*

```
CREATE TABLE student
 (
     id     NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
     name   VARCHAR2 (20),
     age    NUMBER
);

SELECT sequence_name FROM ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS
WHERE table_name = 'STUDENT';

-- TMP Table
CREATE TABLE student_tmp
 (
     id     NUMBER,
     name   VARCHAR2 (20),
     age    NUMBER
);
```

The important part is *GENERATED `BY DEFAULT` AS IDENTITY*, so you can both let the DB to assign the key or you may pass it in the `insert` statement.

Under to hood of the identoty is a plain sequence, the name you get with the following query:

```
SELECT sequence_name FROM ALL_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS
WHERE table_name = 'STUDENT';
```

*Prepare Data*

```
INSERT INTO student_tmp (id, name, age)
WITH dt(name, age) AS (
SELECT 'monica', 23 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'saroop', 34 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
  ISEQ$$_85678.nextval,  -- use here the IDENTITY sequence
  name, age 
FROM dt;
```

Now you have all data in the TMP table, you may check and process the new ID's with

```
SELECT id, name, age FROM student_tmp;
```

*Publish Data*

This is a plain INSERT

```
INSERT INTO student(id, name, age)
SELECT id, name, age 
FROM student_tmp;
```

I'm leaving out details as exceptions, transactions and hint for direct insert - set it on your requirements.